# Maneiras de inicializar struct's

Tags: c, struct, inicialização

Conheço essas duas maneiras de inicializar `struct`'s.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    char s[10];
    int a, b;
    double x;
} TIPO;
int main(){
    TIPO v1[10]={"foo", 5, 13, 4.3, "bar", 0, 0, 2.3};
    TIPO v2[10]={{"FOO", 10, 1, .3},{ "Barrr", 10, -20, 39.22}};
    printf("%s : %d : %d : %.3lf\n", v1[0].s,  v1[0].a, v1[0].b, v1[0].x);
    printf("%s : %d : %d : %.3lf\n", v1[1].s,  v1[1].a, v1[1].b, v1[1].x);
    printf("%s : %d : %d : %.3lf\n", v2[0].s,  v2[0].a, v2[0].b, v2[0].x);
    printf("%s : %d : %d : %.3lf\n", v2[1].s,  v2[1].a, v2[1].b, v2[1].x);
}
```

Resultado:

```
foo : 5 : 13 : 4.300
bar : 0 : 0 : 2.300
FOO : 10 : 1 : 0.300
Barrr : 10 : -20 : 39.220
```

Quais outras maneiras de inicializar `structs` em C11/C18?

Como inicializar, digamos, `b=1` para todos os elementos de `v1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O fato de algo funcionar não quer dizer que deva usar sempre, alguns casos funcionam por coincidência, em uma situação específica, eu faria do jeito mais semântico sempre.

Basicamente consigo lembrar de um caso normal (pode ter outros que eu não lembre ou truques possíveis) que é o uso dos membros nomeados em vez de posicional:

```
TIPO v3[10] = {{ .s = "FOO", .a = 10, .b = 1, .x = .3 }, { .a = 10, .s = "Barrr", .b = -20, .x = 39.22 }};
```

Outra forma:

```
TIPO v3[10];
strcpy(v3[0].s,"FOO");
v3[0].a = 10;
v3[0].b = 1;
v3[0].x = .3;
v3[1].a = 10;
strcpy(v3[1].s, "Barrr");
v3[1].b = -20;
v3[1].x = 39.22;
```

Fora isto você pode criar abstrações que te ajudem, mas dentro dessas abstrações sempre será a forma que usou na pergunta ou essas novas que te mostrei, aí claro usará variáveis e não literais como é o exemplo da pergunta. Você deve avaliar se essas abstrações são necessárias, em C usa-se menos abstrações do que em outras linguagens. Dei exemplos sem elas porque a pergunta usa de forma crua.

Para inicializar um membro igual para todos elementos seria algo assim )depende exatamente do que quer):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v1[i].b = 1;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Vnur1R). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MemberInitialization). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/MemberInitialization.c).

Lembrando que isto não inicializará outros membros. Se quiser isso tem que faze o mesmo para cada um deles.

Answer (score 1):

C é uma linguagem de médio/baixo nível, sem suporte direto a objetos. As structs são uma forma bem legal de indicar para o compilador um layout de uma área de memória, e com sintaxe para preencher e editar vários campos dessa área )das structs).

Mas structs são essencialmente "burras" - elas não sabem nada - é como se fosse uma régua de gabarito em cima de um papel em branco. Só o assignment (uso do operador `=`) preenche essas áreas de memória com os valores desejados, durante a execução do programa.

O que você precisa para dar "inteligência" para as structs é criar uma série de funções, uma para cada coisa que deseja ara as structs, - pode ser cada uma bem simples mesmo. Em comum, todas elas recebem um ponteiro para a struct que você vai trabalhar no primeiro elemento - e operando sobre essa estrutura proveem a "inteligência" necessária ao objeto.

Isso de ter "funções associadas a uma estrutura de dados" é essencialmente o primeiro benefício de Orientação a Objetos (depois OO tem alguns outros conceitos, implementados em cima desse, como herança, etc).

Para facilitar a leitura do seu código, coloque o nome da struct, ou tipo de dados, como prefixo das funções.

Nesse caso, para garantir sempre a inicialização com `b=1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    char s[10];
    int a, b;
    double x;
} TIPO;

TIPO * tipo_init(TIPO *tipo) {
   tipo->s[0] = "\x0";
   tipo->a = 0;
   tipo->b = 1;
   tipo->x = 0;
   return tipo
}

TIPO * tipo_init_vector(TIPO * vector, int length) {
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<length; i++) {tipo_init(vector[i]);}
   return vector;
}

TIPO * tipo_create_vector(int length){
   TIPO * vector;
   vector = malloc(length * sizeof(TIPO));
   if (vector != NULL) {
       tipo_init_vector(vector, length);
   }
   return vector;
}

main() {
   TIPO *v1, *v2;
   v1 = tipo_create_vector(10);
   ...
}
```